# Как обмениваться данными с главным процессом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу написать быстрый скрипт для проверки прокси-серверов с использованием multiprocessing. Но проблема в том, что созданный процесс не умеет общаться с глобальными переменными (то есть, с главным процессом). Нашёл способ прикрутить синхронизацию через `multiprocessing.Queue`, но тогда вообще весь multiprocessing теряет смысл, ибо каждый Queue заставляет выполнять процессы синхронно. Попробовал так же применить `lock.acquire()` и `lock.release()`, но это вообще ничего не дало. В чём тогда смысл multiprocessing, если данные никак нельзя вернуть в главный процесс?

**UPD:** вероятно, я как-то неправильно реализую возможности Queue/Pipe?

```
for i in range(len(ips)):
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    proc = Process(target=runProxyChecker, args=(i,child_conn))
    proc.start()
    proxyData = parent_conn.recv()
    if(proxyData['iteration'] == True):
        iterations += 1
        good_proxies.append(proxyData['ip'])
    print('\rProxies left: {}   '.format(str(len(ips) - iterations)), end="")
# terminating processes
```

В документации не описано создание большого количества процессов, синхронизирующихся с главным процессом. Возможно, нужно один родительский Pipe, объявленный до цикла, а в теле цикла нужно объявить дополнительный Pipe для дочернего процесса?

Comment: Очередь не заставляет процессы выполняться синхронно. С чего вы это взяли?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev возможно, я неправильно реализую возможности очереди/pipe. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, добавленный код.

Comment: Используй multiprocessing.imap очереди сами создадутся

Comment: @eri то что я пытаюсь написать вообще реализуемо?

Comment: Используй mp.imap - ты удивишься как все круто может быть.

Comment: @eri это вы об [этом](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)?

Comment: добавил ответ, да об этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

ips = [...]

workers = Pool(16)

def check_proxy(ip):
    if ...:
       return true,ip
    return false,ip

l = len(ips)
c = 0
good_proxies =[]
for i,ip in workers.imap_unordered(check_proxy, ips):
    if i:
         print("{} - good\n".format(ip))
         good_proxies.append(ip)
    print("{}/{}\r".format(c,l))
```

Всё просто делается с map. 16 процессов таскают элементы из массива и возвращают проверив. `imap_unordered` возвращает по мере исполнения функции в неотсортированном виде - то есть "как только - так сразу".

Comment: Реализовал. Работает просто шикарно. Спасибо большое!