# Обмен данными между главным процессом и дочерним Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Запускается программа и в ней создается процесс в котором вызывается функция:
    
    `self.p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.task_copyer_auto)
    self.p1.start()`

как сделать, чтобы в функция в этом процессе изменяла переменную, которую можно будет использованть в главном процессе?

Comment: [Как обмениваться данными с главным процессом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927016/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def f(n):
    n.value = 3.1415927


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
```